# How to associate only a subdomain to my Django App on Digital Ocean?

Tags: django, digital-ocean

We already have a website called `X.com`. Now I am building a Django App on a Digital ocean Droplet. I am able to access it using the IP-address.
But we want to have it called `reporting.X.com` for sharing it with our users.
On my domain providers, I already added an A record like the below

```
Host- reporting
Type - A
Content - <ip-address> of digital ocean droplet
```

However I keep getting the following message when I try to access `reporting.X.com`.
What should I do?

```
Welcome to nginx!
If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and working. Further configuration is required.

For online documentation and support please refer to nginx.org.
Commercial support is available at nginx.com.

Thank you for using nginx.
```

Answer (score 2):

Okay I have resolved the issue. So I will answer this for future reference of other people.

You need to check 2 important places.

1. `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/<your_project>`

If you want your django app with just the subdomain, your project file in sites-enabled should look like below.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name <ip-address> .X.com;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/<user>/<project>;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/<user>/<project>.sock;
    }
```

The `dot` in front of `X.com` is not a typo. This basically says any sub domain for `X.com`.

2. `settings.py` file in Django App

You have to set `ALLOWED_HOSTS` this way.
`ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['ip-address', '.X.com']`
Again `X.com` is preceded with a `dot`.

In the question, I already mentioned that I created an `A` record with following details.

```
Host- reporting
Type - A
Content - <ip-address> of digital ocean droplet
```

After this, restart your nginx server.
`sudo systemctl restart nginx`

Now, theoretically it should work. But if it doesn't (as it didn't for me), **you have to shutdown and restart your droplet.**

`sudo shutdown -r now`

My Django app started to work after this activity.
Hope it helps.

Comment: spot-on! I've followed your steps, got a challenge where my site shows a 404 and prompts a re-direct to vercel, my nameserver. Any advice on this? My goal was to have my backend have a subdomain as well as my frontend.`back-api.domain.com` and `front.domain.com`